# Markdown in python cell

Tags: python, jupyter, indentation

Is it possible to have python code under the same indentation in two cells in a jupyter notebook.

e.g.

```
{def circuit(X):
      icecream = make_param(...)}
```

----another cell-----

```
      {with eng:
            BSgate(icecream=icecream)}
```

error : icecream is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Block of code must be in the same cell in order to be executed. Kernel is running each cell asynchonously (as detailed in [the documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Running%20Code.html#Code-cells-allow-you-to-enter-and-run-code)) and interactively displaying intermediate results. This is one if the reasons why each cell has to be “executable” as a whole block and you can’t split if/else statements, function definitions, loops and such across the cells.